# Getting time with PHP/mySQL and wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, time

I got a little problem over here. It's about wordpress plugin but support will probably answer me in 1-2days. Maybe someone over here know the answer.

I am using myCRED plugin. It gives mi permission to give some user points on my website. So when I am giving someone points via wordpress panel then in mySQL table there is a column "time". Could someone figure this out?

```
Date -> php code entry in "time" column
April 24, 2014 4:28 pm -> 1398356897
April 24, 2014 3:27 pm -> 1398284766
April 23, 2014 4:30 pm -> 1398270617
```

I want to make php script which will add record to this table but I don't know how to fill "time" column corectly. Anyone here know function for this?

That's what I tried //you shouldn't really care about other variables. Just about the last one column called "time".

```
$time = time();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_myCRED_log (user_id, creds, entry, time)
VALUES (".$_POST['user_id'].", '-".$_POST['price']."', 'Bought:".$_POST['reward']."', '".$time."' ; )");
```

If you still don't know what I mean just ask :)

Regreds,
Guy with a problem.

Comment: um, try php function: `time()` for the unix timestamp: 1398270000 or use the mysql function `now()` to get the date and time.

Comment: As others have said, you can use time() or now() to insert the time into your db.  But there's nothing wrong with storing the unix timestamp in your database.  You can always convert it later when you display it on your website in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Unix [timestamp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) representing the date.

Comment: Thanks. Used this and made what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use php's Time() function to get the current unix timestamp.

i.e.

`$time = time();`
and then insert the $time variable into your query.

Use "$time" in your query since php will take the $ literally in single ticks, and use date(); as need to display this as a date.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_myCRED_log (user_id, creds, entry, `time`)
VALUES (".$_POST['user_id'].", '-".$_POST['price']."', 'Bought:".$_POST['reward']."', '".$time."' ; )");
```

Comment: I tried it and it's not working. Could you please help me with it? Even with this code it's not working. I edited my main post.

Comment: @user3565273 PHP Variables cannot be used in single ticks, change that to: "$time" in your query.

Comment: Not working. When I use like you said I am not even adding a record to my table. When I delete "time" as a column and value I am getting record but with "NULL" time. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3565273 Sorry, I mistyped something. Try now. Forgot you had your entire sql statement in quotes, so I had to concatenate the string.

Comment: Nah, nothing. Thats how I added it before and it's still not working. Please remember that I want Unix timestamp and just send it to mySQL. I think I found it already, but it's 2late to check it. Thanks you anyway :)